# python how can I find out the duplicate elements in a three dimensional list

Tags: python, list

I have a list as follows:

```
list2=
[[((2, 2), (5, 5)), (4.0, 4.0)], [((4, 2), (4, 8)), (4.0, 4.0)], 
[((5, 6), (3, 8)), (4.0, 7.0)], [((4, 2), (4, 8)), (4.0, 7.0)], 
[((5, 6), (3, 8)), (4.0, 7.0)], [((1, 4), (5, 8)), (4.0, 7.0)], 
[((4, 2), (4, 8)), (4.0, 7.0)], [((1, 4), (5, 8)), (4.0, 7.0)]]
```

What I what to do is to find out duplicate element in `list[i][0]`, for example

```
[((4, 2), (4, 8)), (4.0, 4.0)] ,[((4, 2), (4, 8)), (4.0, 7.0)]
```

(`list2[1][0]` and `list2[6][0]` are the same),then add the `(4.0,7.0)` in the latter one to the former one, then delete the latter one from list2

I try to use a loop to implement, but it does not work.
my code:

```
list3=list2
i=range(0,len(list2))
j=range(0,len(list2))
  for i in list2:
      for j in list3:
        if list2[i][0]==list3[j][0] and list2[i][1]!=list3[j][1]:
        list2[i].append(list3[j][1])
        list2.pop(j)
```

Any suggestion will be helpful! Thank you

Comment: sorry, a mistake in my post, What I want to do is to find out duplicate element in list[i][0]

Comment: You assign the range to i, j then use them as values for your loop...You also set the lists equal to one another...

Comment: why are you using a bit-wise operator & ?

Comment: Please edit your question to format input data with line breaks and padding so it's readable and correct what exactly you want. Pay attention to the comment about "&" operator - should be used "and" here.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. `list[0]` is `[((2, 2), (5, 5)), (4.0, 4.0)]` and your example the duplicates between the two lists are `[4, 2, 8, 4.0]` so please edit your question.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, this is the first time I ask question. I will pay attention next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming duplicates have identical first items but differing last items. I'm also assuming that order of the resulting list doesn't matter (hence the sorting for faster runtime):

```
def reduceDups(lst):
  lst = sorted(lst)
  i = 0
  while(i < len(lst)):
    if(i < len(lst) - 1):
      # Get reference elements
      (refFirst, refLast) = (lst[i][:-1], lst[i][-1])

      # Get first, last elements of possible duplicate
      (dupFirst, dupLast) = (lst[i + 1][:-1], lst[i + 1][-1])

      if(refFirst == dupFirst):
        # Next element is identical (by our comparison). Get rid of it
        lst.pop(i + 1)
        lst[i].append(dupLast)
      else:
        i += 1
    else:
      i += 1

  return lst
```

For the input list, this gives:

```
[[((1, 4), (5, 8)), (4.0, 7.0), (4.0, 7.0)],
 [((2, 2), (5, 5)), (4.0, 4.0)],
 [((4, 2), (4, 8)), (4.0, 4.0), (4.0, 7.0)],
 [((4, 2), (4, 8)), (4.0, 7.0)],
 [((5, 6), (3, 8)), (4.0, 7.0), (4.0, 7.0)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use tuples as keys of a dict, so it's really quite easy (if I understand the question right, that is)

```
d={}
for x in list2:
    d.setdefault( x[0], [] ).append(x)
for k,v in d.items():
    if len(v) > 1:
       # v is a list of members of list2 sharing a common v[0]
       print(v)
```

with your list2 I get this output

```
[[((1, 4), (5, 8)), (4.0, 7.0)], [((1, 4), (5, 8)), (4.0, 7.0)]]
[[((4, 2), (4, 8)), (4.0, 4.0)], [((4, 2), (4, 8)), (4.0, 7.0)]]
```